# Using CLIPS in selection in matrix

Tags: clips

Given a 10*10 matrix which is filled with 0~9. It is required that we only pick 3 integers in each row and each vertical column to make sure the integers we choose is the largest in the matrix. How to make it using the CLIPS(c language integrated production system)? P.S. Each row and vertical column can have the 0~9 only once.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If each row/column has 0-9 in each column/row just once, you'd pick 9, 8, and 7.

Comment: Yes, it seemed that I should pick 9, 8, and 7. Then how can I use CLIPS to select them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd find the elements for a row

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate element
   (slot row)
   (slot column)
   (slot value))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts start
   (element (row 1) (column 1) (value 3))
   (element (row 1) (column 2) (value 5))
   (element (row 1) (column 3) (value 9))
   (element (row 1) (column 4) (value 8))
   (element (row 1) (column 5) (value 1))
   (element (row 1) (column 6) (value 7))
   (element (row 1) (column 7) (value 2))
   (element (row 1) (column 8) (value 4))
   (element (row 1) (column 9) (value 0))
   (element (row 1) (column 10) (value 6))

   (element (row 2) (column 1) (value 1))
   (element (row 2) (column 2) (value 3))
   (element (row 2) (column 3) (value 5))
   (element (row 2) (column 4) (value 7))
   (element (row 2) (column 5) (value 9))
   (element (row 2) (column 6) (value 0))
   (element (row 2) (column 7) (value 8))
   (element (row 2) (column 8) (value 6))
   (element (row 2) (column 9) (value 4))
   (element (row 2) (column 10) (value 2)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule largest-in-row
   (element (row ?r) (column ?c1) (value ?v1))
   (not (element (row ?r) (column ~?c1) (value ?v&:(> ?v ?v1))))
   (element (row ?r) (column ?c2&~?c1) (value ?v2))
   (not (element (row ?r) (column ~?c1&~?c2) (value ?v&:(> ?v ?v2))))
   (element (row ?r) (column ?c3&~?c2&~?c1) (value ?v3))
   (not (element (row ?r) (column ~?c1&~?c2&~?c3) (value ?v&:(> ?v ?v3))))
   =>
   (printout t "r" ?r " : c" ?c1 "=" ?v1 " c" ?c2 "=" ?v2 " c" ?c3 "=" ?v3 crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
r2 : c5=9 c7=8 c4=7
r1 : c3=9 c4=8 c6=7
CLIPS>
```